# PHP Script - Adding a randomizing array to $fcontents which goes sequentially?

Tags: php

Trying to make this script go random. I tried variations of this string `$banner_no = rand(1,$max)-1;`

```
<div id="header_banner_ad">
    <?php
        $fcontents = join ('', file ('FILENAME'));
        $s_con = split("~",$fcontents);
        $banner_no = rand(1,(count($s_con)-1));
        echo $s_con[$banner_no];
    ?>
</div>
```

I'm not entirely sure what to do.

Comment: you need to explain the file structure that you load

Comment: `split()` is deprecated, use `explode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan't to select a random element from an array you could use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Example:

```
$random = array_rand($s_con);
echo $s_con[$random];
```

Comment: a little note on using `array_rand`; the function selects a random key from the array passed as parameter, that might not be clear to users unfamiliar with the function. [array_rand documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)